# Pixi.js in SvelteKit gives a 'self is not defined' error only while building

Tags: typescript, pixi.js, sveltekit

As the title states, when using Pixi.js in SvelteKit, ONLY and ONLY while building the application, it will spit out a "self is not defined" error, and it traces back to the `@pixi/settings` module. I have tried every possible way that I know to fix this. First I used a shim to give it some dummy information, but that didn't work:

```js
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    globalThis.window = {} as any;
}
if (typeof self === 'undefined') {
    globalThis.self = globalThis.window;
}
if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
    if (window.document) {
        globalThis.document = window.document;
    } else {
        globalThis.document = window.document = {
            createElement: (elementName: string) => {
                switch (elementName) {
                    case 'canvas':
                        return {
                            getContext: (contextName: string) => {
                                switch (contextName) {
                                    case 'webgl':
                                        return {
                                            getExtension: () => {}
                                        };
                                    case '2d':
                                        return {
                                            fillRect: () => {},
                                            drawImage: () => {},
                                            getImageData: () => {}
                                        };
                                }
                            }
                        };
                }
            }
        } as any;
    }
    if (typeof CanvasRenderingContext2D === 'undefined') {
        globalThis.CanvasRenderingContext2D = { prototype: {} };
    }
}
export {};
```

The shim gives all the necessary dummy informations and variables needed to run, but I guess it doesn't matter on build. Then I tried to import pixi.js dynamically onMount inside the code like so:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import '$utils/pixi-ssr-shim';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import App from './utils/App';
    import { run } from './seating-chart';

    let el: HTMLDivElement;

    onMount(async () => {
        //@ts-ignore
        const PIXI = await import('pixi.js');

        run(el, PIXI);

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            App.app.destroy(true);
            App.app = null;
            App.viewport = null;

            run(el, PIXI);
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="flex items-center justify-around">
    <div bind:this={el} />
</div>
```

I also tried creating my own bundle of pixi.js like how pixijs.io/customize do, and that only creates another issue that I couldn't be bothered with.

So, I have no idea what to do to fix this, because I cannot just go around the error and run the program.

Comment: please read https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/7703

Comment: I have actually read this before putting this question together, and the problem I am having is that it errors out while ONLY on build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually caused by the pixijs code having used `self` in their code and when the sveltekit compiler analyzes it, it errors out because nodejs doesn't have self as a variable, I have fixed this issue and created a pull request into the main branch of pixijs that will be released at 6.3.0.

Here's the PR:
https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/pull/8050

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related but I added Pixi to my Svelte project (based on the official Svelte starter template using rollup) and I started to get this error:

```
ReferenceError: url$1 is not defined
```

It was coming from my bundle "in general" and didn't point to a specific point of failure.

After some searching I found that adding the `preferBuiltins: false` setting to my `resolve` plugin settings in `rollup.config.js` fixed it (where `resolve` is the import from the `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` plugin.

So in `rollup.config.js`:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      ...
      preferBuiltins: false,
      ...
    })
  ]
  ...
}
```